# Do complete and run RET in company

Tags: company-mode

I'd like to use a super small value of `company-minimum-prefix-length`, for example, `2`. This is really handy and I don't feel any performance issue. The only thing that annoys me is, when in inferior shell mode(inferior-python-mode, inferior-ess-mode, shell-mode ...), some commands are short, i.e. `ls`, what I actually want is to run the command after I press `RET` even there was company tooltip displaying the candidates before I press `RET`. But what I got is `company` did the completion and I need to press `RET` to run the command.

Because this will happen even when `company-minimum-prefix-length` is set to a large value, for example, `5`,

[image]

Rather than set a larger value of `company-minimum-prefix-length`, I'd like to tell `company` to do completion and and run the command of `RET` of current major mode if current candidate is already exactly the same as the prefix I typed ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here's a small solution for this. Bind `C-m` to nil in `company-active-map` and whenver you encounter a situation like you described, press `RET` to complete the company candidate or press `C-m` to just execute return without company completing the candidate.

Comment: @ChakravarthyRaghunandan Thanks for your suggestions. But for me I rarely use keystrokes like `C-j` and `C-m`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a dirty solution

```
(defun company-immediate-completion-and-run (orig-func &rest args)
  (let ((prefix company-prefix)
        (candidate (nth company-selection company-candidates)))
    (prog1 (apply orig-func args)
      (if (string= prefix candidate)
          (call-interactively (key-binding (kbd "RET")))))))
(advice-add 'company-complete-selection :around #'company-immediate-completion-and-run)
```

There is a hook `company-completion-finished-hook` but it seems that we must record the `prefix` and `candidate` before finished because once the completion is finished, `company` will set both back to `nil`. More elegant solutions are welcome.

Comment: Why `symbol-function`?

Comment: @Stefan I tested and it seems that `symbol-function` is indeed not necessary. Thanks for pointing out this. When I wrote the snippet, I though it would be necessary to use it.

Comment: Not only it's not necessary, but it would introduce a bug when the RET key is bound to an autoloaded command (that hasn't yet been loaded).